# Not seeing the basalmiq tool icon in the question editor

Tags: support, mockups

When I create a new question, I do not see the icon that is supposed to open the Basalmiq editor, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of my editor, missing the Balsalmiq icon]

Is this working as designed, or is this a bug? I believe I have sufficient reputation points.

Comment: That looks like Meta; Balsamiq is only on the main site. Do you see it on the main site as well?

Comment: My bad! I didn't notice the distinction between the two sites.

Comment: @balpha - Why did you change the tags on this?

Comment: @CharlesBoyung Because it was tagged incorrectly. [meta-tag:status-completed] was wrong (there was nothing completed, because there was nothing broken or missing in the first place), and the [meta-tag:mockups] tag, which should be on all questions about the balsamiq editor, was missing. Why would I not retag it?